# Use printf in embedded c

Tags: c, embedded

I work on the Aurix microcontroller on eclipse
i need to display unsigned char values on the console,
I did like that

```
  printf ("% hhx", tab [j]);
```

but I had this error:

```
  error: AppKit_TC277TFT_TimeDemo.elf section `.inttab' will not fit in 
  region `PMI_PSPR'

  error: region `PMI_PSPR' overflowed by 16788 bytes
```

Is there anyone who could help me

Comment: so what is the solution?

Comment: Download more RAM. Jokes aside, you should have thought about the requirements of your project before buying an MCU.

Comment: OK so it was not possible to printf with this MCU?

Comment: Note that you do not really need `printf` to do ~`% hhx` or `%0hhx` - there are gazillion examples on SO on how to do it without

Comment: @Antti I will try to display the value in a log file, I think it's better

Comment: The size is because `printf` cannot know in advance what the requirements will be — format strings may be generated at run-time — and must include code for every possibility.

Comment: @Rbn Have you done anything weird to the configuration of the compilation? Given that this processor has more instruction cache than many MCUs have total memory, I can't imagine that a `printf` is a big deal, unless you've already got a big application.

Comment: do not use printf. Write tiny own one

Comment: Looking at the datasheet, your MCU(TC27x_DS_DC) has 4MB of program flash. How big is your project?

Comment: @VioAriton It has a huge amount of flash, but the segment being overflowed is only 24 kB in size.

Comment: I did not change anything in the compiler configuration,
if not even if I write a simple application that contains printf ("hello"), I had the same error

Comment: The thing with printf is that it is 1) incredibly slow, 2) incredibly memory-consuming and 3) incredibly error-prone. Meaning that you should never use it in production code for embedded systems - you should in fact stay clear of the whole stdio.h. You are going to want some error handler and/or logger in the actual application, so start by developing that one. Use UART, CAN, SPI or whatever is most suitable.

Comment: @Lundin: see what I mean, worst case would be, if that printf's will be part of a valdiation concept in a safety critical system. Then you can not take that stuff out, because it "might otherwise change the runtime behaviour" and you can not prove that it's working the same as with the printf the same way.

Comment: @kesselhaus Good thing then that the whole of stdio.h is banned by MISRA-C, so it will never make it inside a professionally developed safety-critical system. You may use it in debug build but not in production code.

Comment: printf... incredibly slow... well, it probably goes to uart, so yes, it's slow. Execution time parsing string format should pale in comparison to uart.

Comment: @domen Hello DMA. Or ring buffers. But yes, UART is obsolete technology - it only has one single advantage: being wildly available.

Answer (score 4):

Searching for *PMI_PSPR Aurix* in a well-known search service brings up [this forum post](https://www.infineonforums.com/threads/4728-Memory-mapping-for-TC27xTF).

Apparently you are linking your code to run from RAM. Change the linker settings to link it to flash, and run from there.

Answer (score 1):

First try to isolate what is the cause.  Two thoughts are:

1. Check if the stdout stream works.
2. Check if a memory issue (as the error suggests).

### 1. stdout check:

Try using the stdout stream without using printf formatter.  The formatter is bloated as people suggest and generally not a good idea on embedded systems.  Also have you setup where the stdout stream goes (is it mapped to some UART code, normally on embedded systems you need to write or configure this)?  Test by using putch('.'), putchar('.') or even puts("Hello").

### 2. memory check:

Try building the code that uses sprintf() by itself without stdout.  If that doesn't build either then it is likely the formatter. Some embedded compilers allow configuring the formatter library as smaller options to get around this issue (doesn't support the full implementation).

Answer (score 1):

> Use printf in embedded c

One way is to use UART communication.

Convert numeric value to printable ascii form and send to UART so that one may see on console.

For simple applications you may consider storing printable characters to some array buffer and at the end of activity print the array buffer to UART